# Flash compile error 1017

Tags: apache-flex

I'm getting this error when compiling a newly created application with SDK 4.1:

1017: The definition of base class Application was not found.

I can click on the SDK library path in the Flash Builder Explorer and navigate to the spark->components->Application object.

At least one other application linked to the same SDK compiles just fine.

Comment: Show your code, and specifically the line that is throwing the error.  If you recently changed the SDK on the project in Flash Builder, be sure to clean.

Comment: There is no code, this is a fresh project with one .mxml that contains an s:Application tag and no children.

Comment: post a screenshot of: version of eclipse, of SDK settings window, of plugin folder with SDKs in yr %USER% folder.

Answer (score 0):

For current time, the best solution will be:

1. Try to make a flex3 project, and let us know if it works.
2. Try to download any sample 4.1 project and try to compile, and let us know.
3. If you are using flex builder pack, use a plugin pack instead. Or conversely.
4. Try uninstall it completely and reinstall again.
5. Check if sdk 4.1 exist in your C:\Users\%USER%\AppData*Adobe*\ folder.

Let us know.

Thank you.